# java recursion: best collection of numbers

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

Given an array of integers and given another integer. How to use recursion to find a collection of integers from that array so that the sum of the collection is closest to that given integer?
For example, given array:1,2,3 and the given integer is 5, then the method returns 2,3;
another example: if the given array is: 35,14,45,3 and the given integer is 50, then the method returns 35 and 14.

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: Homework? Post what you tried please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a *homework*, so I'll not put any code, but try to *explain the algorithm*.
Imagine, that you're given `[35, 14, 45, 3]` and `50`;

```
  1. First sort the array in descending order: [45, 35, 14, 3] 
  2. You should remove the 1st item in the array and take it or leave it
  3. So you'll have two smaller problems: 
      [35, 14, 3] and 5  (45 is taken)
      [35, 14, 3] and 50 (45 is left)
  4. To cut story short keep the best score so far: 5 in your case. 
     It let you trim some negative value branches
      [35, 14, 3] and 5  (45 is taken) is the best so far 
  5. If the array is not empty, go to the step 2
```

The whole trace is

```
  [35, 14, 3] and   5 (45 taken) // the best score so far
      [14, 3] and -30 (45, 35 taken) // trim: worse than the best score so far
      [14, 3] and   5 (45 taken)
          [3] and  -9 (45, 14 taken) // trim
          [3] and   5 (45 taken)
           [] and   2 (45, 3 taken) // the best score so far
           [] and   5 (45 taken)    
  [35, 14, 3] and  50 (nothing taken)
      [14, 3] and  15 (35 taken)
          [3] and   1 (35, 14 taken) // the best score so far
           [] and  -2 (35, 14, 3 taken) 
          [3] and  15 (35 taken) 
           [] and  12 (35, 3 taken) 

       ...
```

finally, the best score so far `1` is the solution with `(35, 14)` taken. 
When implementing, you can just  make two *recursive calls*: one for "take" and one for "leave".

Comment: Thanks! It's an assignment, and I tried like this: for every element in the array, call the recursive method(calculate the best) with an array excluding that element, and the corresponding integer subtracting that element...and then I cannot figure out what to return for the base case. Recursion for me is quite tough.